# How to test if JSON Collection object is empty in Java

Tags: java, json

The JSON Collection object I'm receiving looks like this:

```
[{"foo1":"bar1", "foo2":"bar2", "problemkey": "problemvalue"}]
```

What I'm trying to test for is the existence of `problemvalue`. If `problemvalue` returns a JSON Object, I'm happy.  If it doesn't, it will return as `{}`.  How do I test for this condition?  I've tried several things to no avail.

This is what I've tried thus far:

```
//      if (obj.get("dps") == null) {  //didn't work
//      if (obj.get("dps").equals("{}")) {  //didn't work
if (obj.isNull("dps")) {  //didn't work
    System.out.println("No dps key");
}
```

I expected one of these lines to print "No dps key" because `{"dps":{}}`, but for whatever reason, it's not. I'm using `org.json`. The jar file is `org.json-20120521.jar`.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

```
obj.length() == 0
```

is what I would do.

Answer (score 45):

If you're okay with a hack -

```
obj.toString().equals("{}");
```

Serializing the object is expensive and moreso for large objects, but it's good to understand that JSON is transparent as a string, and therefore looking at the string representation is something you can always do to solve a problem.

Comment: The best answer

Comment: It adds calculation and cpu load and not so good approach.

Comment: @HamidAraghi not really, the underlying representation is already a `HashMap` with `String` keys, so the conversion is quite speedy. The "faster" approach, if that's necessary for extremely large JSON objects, is to compare the `length()` as demonstrated in other answers. But this approach is hardly slow, even in that case.

Comment: in my case I had to use .equals("[]") as the object itself came as null.

Answer (score 14):

If empty array:

```
.size() == 0
```

if empty object:

```
.length() == 0
```

Answer (score 6):

A JSON notation {} represents an empty object, meaning an object without members. This is not the same as null. Neither it is string as you are trying to compare it with string "{}".
I don't know which json library are you using, but try to look for method something like:

```
isEmptyObject()
```

Comment: thx for your suggestion.  i'm using org.json (jar file org.json-20120521.jar).  it doesn't look like there's a method called isEmptyObject. =(

Comment: @Classified I am not familiar with org.json so this might not be the optimum way. An empty object has no member so therefore method keys() should return iterator with length zero. getJSONObject("problemkey").keys() - check the length of that.

Comment: which library do you use?  I found org.json via a google search so I don't know how good/bad it is but it looked fairly popular.  http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html.  thx again for your responses and help

Comment: At the moment Jackson. But this does not mean that org.json is bad, just different.

Comment: Another workaround would be to convert your problem value to JSON string and compare it with string "{}". Something like obj.get("dps").toString().equals("{}"). But check what does toString actualy return regarding to whitespaces.

Comment: If the object is a Map then isEmpty() works, but one must first cast to java.util.Map.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
if (record.has("problemkey") && !record.isNull("problemkey")) {
    // Do something with object.
}
```

Comment: thx for the suggestion.  when I tried your code, it thinks {} is not null and prints my message, which is not what i want.  i dont' know why it thinks {} is not null.

Answer (score 3):

For this case, I do something like this:

```js
var obj = {};

if(Object.keys(obj).length == 0){
        console.log("The obj is null")
}
```

Comment: Nice one, but this seems more like JavaScript rather than Java.

Answer (score 2):

I have added isEmpty() methods on JSONObject and JSONArray()

```
 //on JSONObject 
 public Boolean isEmpty(){         
     return !this.keys().hasNext();
 }
```

...

```
//on JSONArray
public Boolean isEmpty(){
    return this.length()==0;        
}
```

you can get it here https://github.com/kommradHomer/JSON-java

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following to check for an empty object

```
obj.similar(new JSONObject())
```

Comment: This is actually pretty clever.  I wouldn't use it on something so small as this, but it's definitely not an empty-check I had thought of before.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to check for the json empty case, we can directly use below code

```
String jsonString = {};
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
if(jsonObject.isEmpty()){
 System.out.println("json is empty");
} else{
 System.out.println("json is not empty");
}
```

this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object getResult = obj.get("dps"); 
if (getResult != null && getResult instanceof java.util.Map && (java.util.Map)getResult.isEmpty()) {
    handleEmptyDps(); 
} 
else {
    handleResult(getResult); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If JSON returned with following structure when records is an ArrayNode:

```
{}client 
  records[]
```

and you want to check if records node has something in it 
then you can do it using a method size();

```
if (recordNodes.get(i).size() != 0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (jsonObj != null && jsonObj.length > 0)
```

To check if a nested JSON object is empty within a JSONObject:

```
if (!jsonObject.isNull("key") && jsonObject.getJSONObject("key").length() > 0)
```

Comment: Please look at [How do I format my Code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and then add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void emptyJsonParseTest() {
    JsonNode emptyJsonNode = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
    Assert.assertTrue(emptyJsonNode.asText().isEmpty());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

javax.json.JsonObject extends Map, so you can use the isEmpty() method of Map.

```
JsonObject dps = obj.getJsonObject("dps");
if (dps != null && !dps.isEmpty())) ... else ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the following code:

```
if(json.isNull()!= null){  //returns true only if json is not null

}
```

Comment: How would the cast go?

Answer (score -3):

Try `/*string with {}*/ string.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("{}"))`, maybe there is some extra spaces or something

Comment: thx for the suggestion.  I checked and there are no extra spaces.  =(