# Convert Json array "[{}]" to "[]" in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to convert my Blank Json array to the Null Json array.

For ex., My Json array is like "[{}]" and if I got this array then automatically converts to "[]".

My code is like as below :

```
JsonObject jo = FetchData.getAllItemsAvg(request.getParameter("where"), request.getParameter("lastNum"),request.getParameter("limitAvgNum"));
JsonArray ja = new JsonArray();
ja.add(jo); // Some times ja like "[{}]" .
```

Comment: It's not an empty array, it is an array containing a single object with no properties.

Comment: Okay, Do you know how to convert?

Comment: Proper answer depends on what is your input (is it string or instance of some kind of JSONArray class) and what JSON library you are using. If it is string then maybe simply `replace` each `{}` with empty string.

Comment: Hi,

My code is like :

JsonArray ja = new JsonArray();
ja.add(jo);
ja.toString().replace("{}", "");

jo = Json Object.

I have tried with this but still not working.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add that information to your question.

Comment: Hi, added.
Please have a look.

Comment: My solution was meant for input which is string (also strings are immutable so `replace` can't affect original string, instead it creates and return new one based on original string). Anyway can we assume you are using gson library? Or is it other library (we need that info to know what methods are available).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the object is empty before adding it to the array.
(assuming you're using [JsonObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)):

```
JsonObject jo = FetchData.getAllItemsAvg(
                          request.getParameter("where"),
                          request.getParameter("lastNum"),
                          request.getParameter("limitAvgNum"));
JsonArray ja = new JsonArray();
if(!jo.isEmpty()){
    ja.add(jo);
}
```

For com.google.gson.JsonObject:

```
JsonObject jo = FetchData.getAllItemsAvg(
                          request.getParameter("where"),
                          request.getParameter("lastNum"),
                          request.getParameter("limitAvgNum"));
JsonArray ja = new JsonArray();
if(!jo.entrySet().isEmpty()){
    ja.add(jo);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to check?
Because I have tried with following but i'm fail :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170338/how-to-test-if-json-object-is-empty-in-java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585492/how-to-test-if-a-jsonobject-is-null-or-doesnt-exist

And so on..

Comment: Yea, i have already tried with this but i'm getting "The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type JsonObject" error.

Comment: Which JsonObject are you using (link to API preferred)?

Comment: Yea got my answer.
Thank you for helping me.
I have use "jo.entrySet().size() > 0" instead of "!jo.isEmpty()"