# Not able to extract array elements from JSON in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have been trying to extract array elements from my JSON, but unable to, so far.

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "Sample JSON": [{
            "Title": "Title1",
            "Audit": [{
                    "auditId": "01",
                    "type": "sampleType",
                    "auditText": "sampleText",
                    "answer": ["Ans1", "Ans2"]
                },
                {
                    "auditId": "02",
                    "type": "sampleType2",
                    "auditText": "sampleText2",
                    "answer": ["Ans1", "Ans2", "Ans3", "Ans4"]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Title": "Title2",
            "Audit": [{
                    "auditId": "03",
                    "type": "sampleType3",
                    "auditText": "sampleText3",
                    "answer": ["Ans1", "Ans2"]
                },
                {
                    "auditId": "04",
                    "type": "sampleType4",
                    "auditText": "sampleText4",
                    "answer": ["Ans1", "Ans2", "Ans3", "Ans4"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to extract the array elements of the array 'answer'.

I get exception in the line indicated in comment in the method below:

```
    public void getAudit(String myJSON) {

        auditList = new ArrayList<AuditList>();
        String title;
        String auditId;
        String type;
        String auditText;
        ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            JSONArray jssArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Sample JSON");
            int jsonArrLength = jssArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildObj = jssArray.getJSONObject(i);
                title = jsonChildObj.getString("Title");

                JSONArray jssArray1 = jsonChildObj.getJSONArray("Audit");
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < jssArray1.length(); i1++) {


                    JSONObject jsonChildObj1 = jssArray1.getJSONObject(i1);
                    type = jsonChildObj1.optString("type");
                    auditText = jsonChildObj1.optString("auditText");

                    auditId = jsonChildObj1.optString("auditId");

                    JSONArray jssArray2 = jsonChildObj1.getJSONArray("answer");
                     //Getting exception in above line

                    for (int j=0; j<jssArray2.length(); j++)
                    {
                        answer.add(jssArray2.get(j).toString()) ;
                    }

                    AuditList aList = new AuditList();
                    aList.setQuesId(auditId);
                    aList.setQuesText(auditText);
                    aList.setQuesTypw(auditType);
                    aList.setAnswer(answer);
                    aList.setCategoryName(title);
                    auditList.add(aList);

                }


            }

.
.
.
.
.
}
```

I found the exception occurring in the line indicated above using the debugger.
Couldn't find a way to extract array elements of the array 'answer'.
Please help.

Comment: which line ?? please share your logcat

Comment: I have mentioned it as a comment in the above method:

JSONArray jssArray2 = jsonChildObj1.getJSONArray("answer");
                     //Getting exception in above line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: What is the exception message?  How about the type, auditId, auditText - are you getting the value of these correctly?

Comment: @lorraine: The exception message is: "org.json.JSONException: Value  at answer of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray".

Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @user7735493 it's clear from your exception, your JSON might've string value for 'answer'. Please Check or use getString() / OptString() then split using ','.

Comment: @Maharith, how do I get individual element of 'answer' array? For eg my 'answer' array is:                     "answer": ["Ans1", "Ans2", "Ans3", "Ans4"].  Using "answer=jsonChildObj1.getString("answer");" gives exception as well.

Comment: @user7735493 can you please share your complete json

Comment: @user7735493 validate your JSON in jsonlint or jsonformatter website

Comment: @Maharith, I validated it using jsonlint. It is valid. The complete JSON is pretty long. I won't accomodate in the question. But I have put a sample of it in the question.

Comment: @user7735493 what exception you get when you tried getString(). Sorry for delay

Comment: @user7735493 Use this [link](https://www.json-generator.com/) to show JSON

Comment: @Maharith, this is the generated URL for my JSON:

http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVnVCdnXpK?indent=2

Comment: @user7735493 exception occurs for you coz in some place you have empty values i.e., "" and array values []

to solve your issue you have to find "" and []

Comment: @user7735493 

 if(!jsonChildObj1.get("answer").toString().equals("")){
        JSONArray jssArray2 = jsonChildObj1.getJSONArray("answer");
  }

try this

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy!

Comment: @user7735493 does my solution solved your trouble. If So do accept my answer ;)

Comment: Sure, sorry for the delay.

Comment: @user7735493 you welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!jsonChildObj1.get("answer").toString().equals("")){ 
   JSONArray jssArray2 = jsonChildObj1.getJSONArray("answer");
   for (int j=0; j<jssArray2.length(); j++)
   {
      answer.add(jssArray2.get(j).toString()) ;
   }
}
```

The exception that occurred to you because of Empty Data (""). To Prevent this validate it and getJSONArray(). [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170338/how-to-test-if-json-object-is-empty-in-java/24129236)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help !

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this kind of stuff is by going to [this link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and then paste my json there and get my class. After that, you can go and add `Gson` to your gradle by adding this line to your `build.gradle`:

`compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'`

Then just create an instance of the created class that you just created and convert json into your target class:

`NewClass classObject = new Gson().fromJson(YOUR_JSON, NewClass.class);`