# How to validate empty JSON object in REST APIs

Tags: json

Empty json object {} inside array is mapping to request and list is showing as size 1.

How to validate this kind of json objects.

```
    {
     "Employee":{
      "name":"Dhruv",
      "code":"emp123",
      "designation":"Accountant",
      "departments":[{}]
      }
    }
```

Employee DTO:

```
public class Employee {
  private String name;
  private String code;
  private String designation;
  private List<Department> departments;
}

public class Department{
  private String deptName;
  private string deptCode;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if JSON Collection object is empty in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170338/how-to-test-if-json-collection-object-is-empty-in-java)

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

The size will be shown as 1 as there is an empty object within the json (Your json is unaware of the model that created it). The only way to check will be,

```
const hasDepartments = Employee.departments 
    && Employee.departments.length 
    && Employee.departments[0].deptCode;
```